# How get check all input the user enters for a certain word in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am new to python programming. I want to call a function whenever the user enters the word `"inventory"` after I prompt them for an input at any point in the game.
At the moment I am doing this:

```
    def myFunction():
        #do something

    userInput = input("Some input")
    someMoreInput = input("Do something")

    if userInput == "inventory" or someMoreInput == "inventory":
        myFunction()
```

The problem with this is that whenver I want to have the user enter something (and that will happen *a lot*) I have to add the variable name to my if statement.

Comment: why need a variable? do `if input("Some input")=="inventory": myFunction()`

Comment: Because I will need to refer to what the user enters at other points in my program. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear.

Comment: See both the answers and see which solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscar's implementation seems to be correct however, if you want to check input every time without declaring a variable; simply use input()

```
def myFunction():
     #do something

while input() != "inventory":
     #print("you did not enter inventory")
     input()
myFunction()
```

this will keep asking for input unless it equals "inventory" and you don't need to use even a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop for this, for instance:

```
userInput = ''
while userInput != 'inventory':
    userInput = input("Enter input: ")
myFunction()
```

Comment: I don't think OP wanted that. He doesn't want consecutive input. Rather he wants not to define variable every time he wants to take an input.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque as you can see in the accepted answer, this _was_ what OP meant. I don't know why my answer wasn't accepted, but at least, can you remove the down vote?

Comment: Ok, but i hope even you will agree that, OP failed to state his problem clearly. I mean no harm :)

Comment: @AhsanulHaque yup, we agree in that :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have understood your question, you don't want to define a variable for your input again and again.

Well, you don't have to. You can compare directly:

```
if input("Some input")=="inventory": 
    myFunction()
```